# How to delete row in html based on cell value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, row

I am trying to delete a row based on a table's cell value.

In my HTML page I have a simple search function. It would send the values in the text box to the database through ajax then PHP and then PHP would create a table dynamically based on what is in the database.

I have tried to check a the cell in the table for a specific value so that if it is true then the current row would be removed, the function name is `checkMatch()`. However it doesn't work.

This is the button in the HTML, the rest of the HTML is just a text box and drop down box:

```
 <input type="button" id="device_search" value="Search" onclick="searchDevice(); checkMatch();"></input>
```

This is the function in the external JavaScript file:

```
function checkMatch()
{
    var row = document.getElementById("thisRow");
    var cell = Row.getElementById("match");
    if(cell[0].innerText = "0%")
    {
        row.deleteRow(this);
    }
}
```

And here's the creating of table in the PHP:

```
if($num_row)
{
    echo "<table id=\"myTable\" border=\"1\">";
    echo "<tr>
    <th>Board ID</th>
    <th>Tester Name</th>
    <th>Board Name</th>
    <th>Current Slot</th>
    <th>Log Created</th>
    <th>Required Slot</th>
    <th>Match</th>
    </tr>";

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $board_id = $row['board_id'];
        $tester_name = $row['tester_name'];
        $board_name = $row['board_name'];
        $config = $row['config'];
        $log_created = $row['log_created'];
        $req_config = $row['configuration'];

        $exploded = explode(",", $req_config);
        $count =  count($exploded);

        $j = 0;

        foreach($exploded as $value)
        {
            $number = strlen($value);
            $arr = str_split($value, $number);

            if(in_array($config, $arr))
            {
                $j += 1;
                $j /= ($count / 100);
                echo $j;
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }

        echo "<tr id = \"thisRow\">
                    <td>$board_id</td>
                    <td>$tester_name</td>
                    <td>$board_name</td>
                    <td>$config</td>
                    <td>$log_created</td>
                    <td>$req_config</td>
                    <td id = \"match\">$j%</td>
                 </tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
```

The column that I'm checking on is the last column which is the `Match` column. My idea is to remove that current row whenever the cell value of `Match` is `0%`. I can't seem to find what's wrong with my codes, I'm not really good at manipulating DOM elements either so there must be some mistake. Any help on this? Or are there others ways, through PHP etc?

Note: I am not trying to delete the row from database. I just want to remove the row whenever `Match` is `0%`.

EDIT, codes for `searchDevice()` in external js file:

```
function searchDevice()
{
    var device_name = $("#device_name").val();
    var tester_type = $("#tester_type").val();
    var page = "database.php";

    if(device_name==""||tester_type=="")
    {
        alert("Please do not leave any blanks.");
    }
    else
    {
        $.post(page, {
            device_name : device_name,
            tester_type : tester_type,
            action : "search"
            }, function(data) {
            $("div#display_board").html(data);
            checkMatch();
        });
    }
}
```

Currently my table does display with all the right values, but it doesn't remove the rows with 0%.

Comment: if `searchDevice()` is an ajax call, by the time `checkMatch()` is excuted, search result is not yet returned. You need to do the `checkMatch()` within `searchDevice()` callback

Comment: @Neverever Tried as you suggested, same problem.

Comment: please post code for `searchDevice()`, also row id should be unique `id="thisRow"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `checkMatch()` should be called at ajax success callback
- `id` should be unique with in HTML document

**PHP**

```
    // use `class` instead of `id`
    echo "<tr class=\"thisRow\">
                <td>$board_id</td>
                <td>$tester_name</td>
                <td>$board_name</td>
                <td>$config</td>
                <td>$log_created</td>
                <td>$req_config</td>
                <td class=\"match\">$j%</td>
             </tr>";
```

**Javascript**

```
function checkMatch()
{
    $("#myTable tr.thisRow").each(function() {
        var thisRow = $(this);
        var match = thisRow.find(".match");

        // note the `==` operator
        if(match.text() == "0%") {
            thisRow.hide(); 
            // OR thisRow.remove();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Ahh yes. Thank you. Up voted as well for being fast and simple answer with explanation. :)